# expo socket emit is not working but on is working

Tags: react-native, socket.io, expo

anyone knows why emit not working? It happens nothing If I click the button.

here is my frontend code:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io';
  const socket = io('http://xxxxx:3000', {
    transports: ['websocket']
  });

  useEffect(() => {

    socket.on('connect', () => {
      setConnected(true);
      console.log('user connected');
    });

    socket.on('getmessage', message => {
      console.log(message);
    });
  });

...

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => socket.emit('getmessage', chatMessage)} style={{padding: 4, borderRadius: 4, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
         <Text>Send</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

and here is my backend code:

```
const http = require('http');

const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const routes = require('./routes/index');

const cors = require('cors');

const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.use(cors());

app.use(express.json());

app.use(routes);

io.on('getmessage', message => {
  console.log(message);
});

io.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log('a user connected');
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server listen');
});
```

...................................................................................................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you change your server side like following and try it out :)

```js
// ... your code 
io.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('getmessage', message => {
    console.log(message);
  });
});
```

Comment: Please consider following getting-started example from https://socket.io/get-started/ :) Glad I could help